# PHP form not sending data to $_POST

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            <input name="test" type="text">
            <input type="password" name="data">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        $name = $_POST['test'];
        $pass = $_POST['data'];
    }
?>
```

I am trying to make a simple form in PHP that users will use for login. When using this code, nothing ever gets put inside the `$_POST`. I am debugging using PHPstorm and I can tell that the request method is definitely POST, but no data is getting passed through. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let's see your php...

Comment: on top of your test.php add var_dump($_POST); Are you sure that nothings gets posted there?

Comment: @Rasclatt I included it in an edit

Comment: <?php not <php. It's a typo or is the real code?

Comment: Do as @Dimi suggests. `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: As you have it, your code works...provided you use a way to print in your script like `echo` as in `echo $pass;`

Comment: When I use print_r($_POST) it outputs Array()

Comment: After you submit the form it is empty?

Comment: Yes. It's saying that both of the indexes are undefined

Comment: Then you have some server problem, or you have a redirect that will not carry over those `$_POST` values, or this is not the script (or a good enough representation) you are using.

Comment: This is line for line the code that I am using for testing. I am using XAMPP with Phpstorm. Do you think I have something setup wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash at the begening of the action parameter of the form tag.

`<form action="/test.php" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "action" from form. It worked for me.

Code: http://nimb.ws/6pXjnz
Output:http://nimb.ws/PvuxZs